# Where can the GDAL executables be found in a QGIS installation?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I run QGIS 1.8.0 Lisboa on a Windows 7 machine.  Yesterday I attempted to install the TauDEM plugin using these instructions: http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2012-June/020807.html

Since doing this the GDAL tools for QGIS do not work with error:

> The process failed to start. Either the invoked program is missing, or
>   you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.

I understand this means they cannot find the GDAL executables.  However, neither can I.  Where actually are the GDAL executables in the QGIS folder?  I assume I then have to add this manually to the Environmental Variables or into the GDAL tool settings in QGIS - is this correct?

PS. I can run GDAL tools through the OSGEO4W Shell so GDAL itself is alive and well.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by GDAL tools? Do you mean gdalwarp and the others?

Answer (score 6):

They should be in the `(C:\path_to\ )OSGeo4W\bin` folder.

Answer (score 5):

OK I solved it.  In the Environmental System Variables the "(C:\path_to\ )OSGeo4W\bin" path was missing from the PYTHONPATH variable.  Adding it results in all the tools working again.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of Ubuntu users, I found the gdal executables in `/usr/bin`.
Try entering

```
which gdalwarp
```

into a terminal to see where the system goes for the known command.